# React- HTTP request is firing on page load

Tags: http, redux, reactjs

I'm just starting to use react and I have this login model component with the following:

```
export default class LoginModal extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.render.bind(this);
    this.state = {showModal: false}
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  login() {
    console.log("Hello. It's Me")
    axios.post('https://crossorigin.me/http://requestb.in/w21igbw2', {
      firstName: 'Fred',
      lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      //this.setState({ showModal: false });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  handleSelect(eventKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`selected ${eventKey}`);
  }
```

In the model itself I have `<Button onClick={this.login()} bsStyle="btn btn-black btn-block">Login</Button>`, but the `login()` function fires as soon as the page loads not when the button is clicked.  Am I doing this the correct way?  Most of this code was written by a co-worker with more react experience than me so I may be putting the login function in the wrong place entirely.  If so please let me know where the function should go.

Comment: My guess is that you're passing it as `{this.login()}` instead of `{this.login}`, effectively calling it immediately instead of passing a reference but without seeing your `render` method that's just a guess.

Comment: That was it, it's sort of working now, except, I just realized the request it's sending is a get request instead of a post.

Comment: That would be a question about axios then. I've no knowledge of that library unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.login()` should be given as `this.login`to the `onClick()` handler

```
<Button onClick={this.login} bsStyle="btn btn-black btn-block">Login</Button>
```